# Knockout: Dynamically duplicating / cloning a form for additional data entry

Tags: javascript, html, forms, knockout.js

noob alert.

I'm just getting started with knockout, I've got a form doing what I want, but I need to be able to dynamically duplicate the form, so that a new set of values can be entered & the seconds set of results will be displayed underneath the existing data (under the hr).

So basically I need the user to be able to click a button that adds another form that doesn't interfere with the existing form. and then add more forms as necessary (specifically, up to 5 more) and all the data sets are displayed below each other.

sorry for the lump of code but I'm not sure what I could safely remove. I've created a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/GEKst/1/.

Any tips much appreciated.

```
<body>
    <!-- This is a *view* - HTML markup that defines the appearance of your UI -->
    <p>Sample rate (Hz):
        <select data-bind="options: sampleRate, value: selectedSampleRate"></select>
    </p>
    <p>MCLK frequency:
        <select data-bind="options: mclk, value: selectedMclk"></select>
    </p>
    <p>TDM channels per line:
        <select data-bind="options: tdmChans, value: selectedTdmchan"></select>
    </p>
    <hr/>
    <!-- render the json -->
    <p class="code">&lt;sample_rate&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedSampleRate"></span>&lt;&#47;sample_rate&gt;
        <br/>&lt;mclk&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedMclk"></span>&lt;&#47;mclk&gt;
        <br/>&lt;tdm_chan&gt;<span data-bind="text: selectedTdmchan"></span>&lt;&#47;tdm_chan&gt;
    </p>
</body>
```

Js:

```
window.onload = startKnockout;

function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    <!-- declare observables -->
    self.selectedSampleRate = ko.observable();
    self.selectedMclk = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTdmchan = ko.observable();
// Define controls
    self.sampleRate = ko.observableArray(['192000', '176400', '96000', '88200', '48000', '44100'])
    self.mclk = ko.observableArray(['AUDIO_MCLK_49M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_24M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_12M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_6M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_3M'])

    self.tdmChans = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 44100 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 48000) {
            return ['2', '4', '8', '16'];
        } else if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 88200 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 96000) {
            return ['2', '4', '8'];
        } else if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 176400 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 192000) {
            return ['2', '4'];
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }, self);
}

// Activates knockout.js
function startKnockout() {
    ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to break apart the AppViewModel into separate areas.
The first part will be the form itself and for the moment all you need is the field s that will hold the values that are selected.
so you will have this for the form

```
function Form() {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedSampleRate = ko.observable();
    self.selectedMclk = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTdmchan = ko.observable();
    // Define controls
    self.tdmChans = ko.computed(function () {
        if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 44100 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 48000) {
            return ['2', '4', '8', '16'];
        } else if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 88200 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 96000) {
            return ['2', '4', '8'];
        } else if (self.selectedSampleRate() == 176400 || self.selectedSampleRate() == 192000) {
            return ['2', '4'];
        } else {
            // do nothing
        }
    }, self);
    return self;
}
```

Then your ViewModel will contain the a couple observable arrays.  one for the Sampling rate, one for the Mclk and another to contain the filled in forms.

```
var Vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.forms = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addForm = function () {
        self.forms.push(new Form());
    };
    self.sampleRate = ko.observableArray(['192000', '176400', '96000', '88200', '48000', '44100']);
    self.mclk = ko.observableArray(['AUDIO_MCLK_49M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_24M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_12M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_6M', 'AUDIO_MCLK_3M']);

    return self;
}
```

You will also need to add a method to add new forms to the array on the ViewModel.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/GEKst/5/)

Comment: thanks - however this appears to have busted the logic that defines the values in the 'TDM channels' drop-down (the list of values is determined by the selected Sample rate value).

Answer (score 0):

Just abstract your form into a separate viewmodel:

```
function FormViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.selectedSampleRate = ko.observable();
    self.selectedMclk = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTdmchan = ko.observable();
    self.sampleRate = ko.observableArray[/* ... */])
    self.mclk = ko.observableArray([/* ... */])
    self.tdmChans = ko.computed(function () { /* ... */ }, self);
}
```

...prepare your AppViewModel to have several of them:

```
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.forms = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addForm = function () {
        self.forms.push(new FormViewModel());
    };
    self.canAddForm = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.forms().length < 5;
    });
}
```

and use the `foreach` binding in your view:

```html
<body>
  <ul class="list-of-forms" data-bind="foreach: forms">
    <li>
      <!-- your individual form definition here -->
    </ul>
  </ul>
  <button data-bind="click: addForm, enable: canAddForm">Add Form</button>
</body>
```

I trust you find out the rest (like how to make a "remove form" button) yourself.

Comment: thanks for the input - I'll probably use the solution below, mainly because I can see it working but I guess they're both the same thing from different angles. cheers.

Comment: *"mainly because I can see it working"* - Are you saying you did not even take the time to understand both solutions, you simply take the one with the jsFiddle link? Wow, that's sad.

Comment: no, it's because when I tried to implement your solution in a fiddle, it didn't work.